# Laravel query pivot result.

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am having problem with my query. I have 4 tables users,prospects,leads,items. All of them related

oneToMany relation Like users hasMany prospects, prospects hasMany Leads, leads hasMany Items.
My Items is the table that I need the data from. Item table is like below.

```
$table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('lead_id');
            $table->string('sales_phase',11); // the sale_phase has 4 category only A,B,C,D
            $table->string('product_name',32);
            $table->decimal('price',8,2)->default(0.00);
            $table->integer('qty');
            $table->integer('probability')->default(0);
            $table->decimal('forcast',8,2)->default(0.00);
            $table->string('note')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
```

I need to get the the sum of forcast and group by sales_phase. I need 2 result.

**1. Get the sum of forcast group by sales_phase and whos lead_id is active(Leads table active=1)**

**2. Get the sum of forcast group by sales_phase for a user. (user>prospect>lead>item)**

For the first result I am able to make the the pivot table by this below query. But how I can pass parameter in where condition, where lead is active. And get result by user;

```
$data = DB::table('items')
                ->select(DB::raw("lead_id,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN sales_phase='New Lead' THEN forcast ELSE 0 END) AS NEW_LEAD, SUM(CASE     

    WHEN sales_phase='Contact' THEN forcast ELSE 0 END) AS CONTACT, SUM(CASE WHEN   

    sales_phase='Quotation' THEN forcast ELSE 0 END) AS QUOTATION, SUM(CASE WHEN    

    sales_phase='Order' THEN forcast ELSE 0 END) AS ORDERS
                    "))
                    ->groupBy('lead_id')
                    ->get();
```

Please help. Im not good enough in sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Eloquent way, using your relations.

Question 1

```
$sum = Item::->with(['leads' => function($query) {
        $query->where('lead', 'active')
    }])
    ->groupBy('sales_phase')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(forcast) AS sum, sales_phase')
    ->pluck('sum', 'sales_phase');
```

Question 2, for user ID X

```
$userSum = User::where('id', X)
    ->with(['prospects.leads' => function($query) {
        $query->where('lead', 'active')
    }])
    ->with(['prospects.leads.items' => function($query) {
        $query->groupBy('sales_phase')
        ->selectRaw('SUM(forcast) AS sum, sales_phase')
    }])->get();
```

Some relevant Laravel docs:

- [Querying relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)
- [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)
- [Eager loading, and constraining eager loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Hi, thanks, I think im close to the solution. For the first answer I can use for a single lead that's working fine. But what if I want all sums of all active leads which I need to pass parameter to lead table active=1; The second one is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I must have mis-read your question first time.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: With is not working, but I use whereHas, now it works. thanks.